# bind value from input text to button value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to bind button values from input text box.
when we click on the button, button value will be shown in text box, if we change value from input text box have to change selected button value too ..

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>val demo</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  input {
    margin: 4px;
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>
  <button>Feed</button>
  <button>the</button>
  <button>Input</button>
</div>
<input type="text" value="click a button">
 
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if we change value from input text box have to change selected button value too` how would you differentiate between selected and unselected button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>val demo</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  input {
    margin: 4px;
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>
  <button>Feed</button>
  <button>the</button>
  <button>Input</button>
</div>
<input type="text" value="click a button">
 
<script>
var button = $();
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  button = $(this);
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
$("input").on("input", function(){
    button.html($(this).val());
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mylee if 'ínput' is in a page and 'buttons' are in another page.. where binding is not working between them,, then how can we solve this ??

Comment: by another page do you mean in frames or iframes?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>val demo</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  input {
    margin: 4px;
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>
  <button>Feed</button>
  <button>the</button>
  <button>Input</button>
</div>
<input type="text" value="click a button">
 
<script>
var actualButton;
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  actualButton = $(this);
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
$("input").on('keyup', function(e){
  if(actualButton === undefined)
    return;

  actualButton.text($(this).val());
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Ohh someone was faster ;)

Comment: if 'ínput' is in a page and 'buttons' are in another page.. where binding is not working between them,, then how can we solve this ??

Comment: yeah sure,, thanx in advance

Comment: sorry,, the two pages added with php,, i con't send with jsfiddle.. is then any hint to bind between one page to another page ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102565/discussion-between-joel-jaun-and-vijju-sena).